# function in one shared library calling a function in another shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have a shared library say **libfile2.so** (which contains *print2()* function definition). Now I create a **libfile1.so** (which contains *print1()* function definition which in turn calls *print2()* function in libfile2.so). Now I create a **main.c** file which contains *main()* function which calls *print1()* by dynamically linking libfile1.so.

But I am getting the following error:

```
./libfile1.so: undefined reference to `print2'**
```

The following are the commands that I am using:

```
gcc -c -fpic file1.c
gcc -shared -o libfile1.so file1.o
gcc -c -fpic file2.c
gcc -shared -o libfile2.so file2.o
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gcc -I. -L. -o main main.c -lfile1
```

Comment: You should show (a) the command line used to build `file1.so` and (b) the command line used to build the executable.  Both are relevant because you might have built the information that `file1.so` needs `file2.so` into `file1.so` with the answer to (a), and in any case, there are ways to avoid the problem in (b).  Note that it is normal for functions in one shared library (e.g. `file2.so`) to call on functions in another shared library (e.g. `libc.so`).  Or consider `libncurses.so` which uses `libc.so`; and so on.

Comment: I am linking main.c to libfile1.so which contains definition of print1() but print1() calls print2() whose definition is in libfile2.so.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that information, and you should show the command lines in full.  Also, your question discusses `file1.so`; your comment discusses `libfile1.so`.  There's a lot of difference between the naming conventions.  The `lib` prefix permits the use of `-lfile1` notation on the linker command line.  Without that prefix, you can't use the shorthand; you must specify the path to the shared object on the link line.  There is also mention of dynamic loading in a comment to the answer.  That should be part of the question too; it changes things a lot, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have called only `print1` in your `main.c`. Then set the path of the `libfile2.so` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Because it will try to find the dependencies of `libfile1.so` while linking with `main.c`.

```
gcc -o file1.o -c file.c
gcc -o file2.o -c file.c
gcc -o libfile2.so file2.o -shared
gcc -o libfile1.so file1.o -L. -lfile2 -shared
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gcc -o main.exe main.o -L. -lfile1
```

If you have called both `print1` and `print2` in `main.c` then link both `libfile1.so` and `libfile2.so` like below.

```
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -o main.exe main.o -L$YOUR_LIB_PATH -lfile1 -lfile2
```

Because all the symbol used in main.c needs to be resolved while generating executable.

Comment: Ok i understand that i need to link both the .so files but why do i get the error that i mentioned in the question if linking happens during run time ?

Comment: In main.c I am calling print1() function (which is in libfile1.so) which in turn calls print2() function (which is in libfile2.so). So why should I link both the .so files?. Also the symbols should be resolved at run time right because we are using shared objects (dynamic linking)?

Comment: @Sunilbn : In that case no need to link `lfile2`. Link only `lfile1` but before that set the path of `lfile2` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Yes i have set the path of lfile1 and lfile2 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still i am getting the same error. I have one more question why should linking happen while compiling, it should happen during run-time right?

Comment: @Sunilbn : Actually while linking lfile1, gcc will check whether the dependencies of lfile1 is available or not. echo `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and check once, because I tried same thing its working fine after path is set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying :). But I am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: ok. Do `ldd libfile1.so` before compiling. If it shows 'libfile2.so => not found`. Then problem in setting path. `ldd` - will display the dependencies path.

Comment: Hey i got it :). We need to link libfile1.so with libfile2.so while creating libfile1.so and then we can link main.c with libfile1.so only. Thanks a lot for the guidance.